# Animating Viewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiviewcontroller

I am working on a project were i need to hide the view and when I click on a button the view should appear, its some thing like animating the view in one view controller?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

when clicking a button you will call a method, so in that method write the below code and you hide the view of you added in view. for example if you add a button means remove that.

```
[button.view removeFromSuperView];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:[self view] cache:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: This is just animating only one view, but what I need is I have two UIVIEWS in one UIViewController when the view controller loads I should show only one view and hide the other view, and when the user clicks on the button the other view should be visible using animation.

Comment: Add two subviews to your main view, each subview being the intended hidden/shown view, do the UIView animation block maheswaran suggested, but also add [self.subView1 removeFromSuperview]; [self.view addSubview:self.subView2]; before calling [UIView commitAnimations];